# Function called assertion fails on a mocked imported class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to test `ClassToTest` in Python 3:

```py
from path.to import ClassThatNeedsMocking

class ClassToTest:

  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def setup(self):
    foo = ClassThatNeedsMocking()
    foo.functionCall()
```

This class is implemented by some other class, so I do a simple setup:

```py
from some.other.path import ClassToTest

class ImplementingClass(ClassToTest):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

I want to mock the `functionCall` in the `ClassToTest` with the following:

```py
class TestClass:

  def testMethod(self):
    patch = mock.patch('path.to.ClassThatNeedsMocking')

    patcher = patch.start()
    patcher = MagicMock()
    patcher.functionCall = MagicMock()

    foo = ImplementingClass()
    foo.setup()

    # Results in an 'Expected to have been called once. Called 0 times.'
    patcher.functionCall.assert_called_once()

    patch.stop()
```

When printing the `foo.functionCall()` in the `ClassToTest` it returns a `MagicMock` object but still the assert fails. Is this the correct testing setup and what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what shall work:

```
@mock.patch('path_to_class_to_test.ClassThatNeedsMocking')
def test_method(patched):
    foo = ImplementingClass()
    foo.setup()
    patched.return_value.functionCall.assert_called_once()
```

First, you need to patch the class *imported* in the class to test (see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6)). If using `import from` the class is assigned to a new object, that lives in the using module, and this is the one that has to be patched.

Second, you need only the patched class - no need for another mock, or starting/stopping a patcher. You may use a decorator (as I did) or a function call to get it. The patching is reverted as soon as you get out of function scope.

Third, you patch the class, but the function is called by the class *instance*, which is `patched.return_value`, so you have to check that.

Comment: Thanks, the whole setup with the patcher start/stop is because I was using `setup` and `teardown` functions. I've changed the test to what you showed because it ends up being much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The final test that uses [MrBean Bremen's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61522439/function-called-assertion-fails-on-a-mocked-imported-class/61524318#61524318) answer is cleaner. For the sake of completeness the error in the example is found here:

```py
class TestClass:

  def testMethod(self):
    patch = mock.patch('path.to.ClassThatNeedsMocking')

    patcher = patch.start()
    #####################
    patcher = MagicMock()
    patcher.functionCall = MagicMock()
    #####################

    foo = ImplementingClass()
    foo.setup()

    patcher.functionCall.assert_called_once()

    patch.stop()
```

The return value of the `patch.start()` call should be used directly to do the assert on:

```py
class TestClass:

  def testMethod(self):
    patch = mock.patch('path.to.ClassThatNeedsMocking')

    patcher = patch.start()

    foo = ImplementingClass()
    foo.setup()

    patcher.return_value.functionCall.assert_called_once()

    patch.stop()
```